# \RedeclareSectionCommand does not work for section - KOMA-Script Report - Lyx

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

**Problem**

I am using KOMA-Script report class `scrreprt`:

I am trying to change the `beforeakip` and `afterskip` of my Section titles:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=12pt,afterskip=-12pt]{chapter}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\sffamily\LARGE}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=10pt,afterskip=-10pt]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=8pt,afterskip=-8pt]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=10pt,afterskip=-6pt]{paragraph}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\sffamily\normalsize}
```

This is what I do which comes up with the following error:

> Missing \endcsname insertred. (3 times)

If I leave out the lines for `\section` and `\subsection` it works perfectly fine.

Hence the question:
Why does the same command not work for subsection and section ? And what do I have to change in order for it to work?

**The full LaTeX code**

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,english,openright, bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.75cm,rmargin=2.5cm,headheight=18pt,headsep=8pt,footskip=26pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=black,  citecolor=black]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage[automark, headsepline, footsepline, plainfootsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead{\headmark}
\ifoot[Test]{Test}
\cfoot[]{}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\ihead[]{}
\chead[]{}
%\ohead{\headmark}
\automark[chapter]{chapter} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=12pt,afterskip=-12pt]{chapter}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\sffamily\LARGE}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=10pt,afterskip=-10pt]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=8pt,afterskip=-8pt]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=10pt,afterskip=-6pt]{paragraph}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\sffamily\normalsize}


\usepackage {blindtext} %creates blindtext
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{comment}

\end{comment}
\chapter{This is a Chapter}
\section{This is a Section}
\subsection{This is a Sub-section}
\subsubsection*{This is sub-sub-section}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

**Log**

> Error line 57 !missing\endcsname inserted. \numexpr\end(document)
>
> Warnining line 1 The marginal notes overrun the paper

Comment: Make a complete example instead of showing only snippets and show the log-file.

Comment: Please check my edit... the error is the output I get out of lyx. The hole log would be a bit long I assume

Comment: A "full preamble" is not a complete example; And your snippet isn't a full preamble anyway as the class is missing. And if I ask for a log, then I have my reasons.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: You might have noticed the title says "lyx" which is not exactly latex, I posted the documentclass above .... It is the full lyx latex preamble. I could now try creating a verifyable latex example but I dont have such, as I am using Lyx. The document class is a koma script report

Comment: Lyx can export your code, so you have a latex example. You will have to produce a full example and show the log. I expanded your snippet to a small document and it compiles without error.  Also be aware that it was *your* choice to use lyx. If this now makes it more difficult and time consuming to get support, this your problem and not mine.

Comment: Please check the edited version. I exported the lyx code and get now the same error in TexMaker. It still works fine without the redeclaring subsection and section. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Rule of thumb: `hyperref` is loaded last.

Comment: Word of advice: you need to know LaTeX basics to properly use LyX. If you treat LyX as a black  box that you feed with text and that outputs a pdf, you will have a very very hard time figuring out what happens, if the black box doesn't do what it should.

Comment: Well I am trying to learn the latex basics, but you have to start somewhere ;) I find lyx slightly easier to start with as it is a bit closer to the classical " word processors"

Comment: Because of your new question  http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320357/43317 it seems that this problem is already solved for you.

Comment: The advice by Johannes_B of loading hyperref last worked it out! Can I close the question somehow or should I delete it ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by comments.