# Change headsep only for \section titles

Tags: koma-script, sections-paragraphs

**Problem**

I would like to increase the headsep on pages that start with a section\subsection or paragraph title.

I redefined the chapter spacing settings (before and afterskip) according to my wishes and it looks brilliant in text. Just if the title is on top of the page the beforeskip doesnt seem to influence the spacing to the headerline.
An example picture below:

[image]

**Question**

Is there a way to redifine the headsep for pages that start with some kind of section title or is it possible to define it somehow in the settings of the \sections ?
I am using koma-script-report-class:

This is the fullcode:

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,english,openright, bibliography=totoc]  {scrreprt}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.75cm,rmargin=2.5cm,headheight=18pt,headsep=8pt,footskip=26pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage[automark, headsepline, footsepline, plainfootsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead{\headmark}
\ifoot[Test]{Test}
\cfoot[]{}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\ihead[]{}
\chead[]{}
\automark[chapter]{chapter} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=12pt,afterskip=12pt]{chapter}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\sffamily\LARGE}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=12pt,afterskip=10pt]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=12pt,afterskip=8pt]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-12pt,afterskip=8pt]{paragraph}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\sffamily\normalsize}
\usepackage {blindtext} 

\setkeys{Gin}{width=\textwidth} 
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=black,  citecolor=black]{hyperref} 
\makeatother
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
\chapter{Introduction}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
\section{This is a Section}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\subsection{This is a Sub-section}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that this is unusual. It would be better to not use such a small headsep.

But if you really want to do this, you can use

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\sectionlinesformat{\vspace*{0pt}}{}{\PatchFailed}
```

Then the beforeskip is also inserted if the section titles (section, subsection etc.) are on top of a new page.

[image]

Additional remarks:

Do not set `\parskip` manually. Use the KOMA-Script option `parskip=half-` instead.

Replace `\clearscrheadfoot` by `\clearpairofpagestyles`. With both commands `\cfoot[]{}` is not needed. And if both the optional and the mandatory argument of `\ifoot` etc. are equal you can use the starred version.

To restart the page numbering use `\pagenumbering` and insert a `\cleardoublepage` or `\cleardoubleoddpage` before this command to ensure that it is excecuted on a righthand page.

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,english,openright, bibliography=totoc,
  parskip=half-
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,margin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.75cm,headheight=18pt,headsep=8pt,footskip=26pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage[automark, headsepline, footsepline, plainfootsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark[chapter]{chapter} 
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}
\ifoot*{Test}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=12pt,afterskip=12pt]{chapter}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\sffamily\LARGE}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-12pt,afterskip=10pt]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[beforeskip=-12pt,afterskip=8pt]{subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\sffamily\normalsize}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\sectionlinesformat{\vspace*{0pt}}{}{\PatchFailed}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\textwidth}% default width for \includegraphics
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter{Introduction}
\Blindtext
\cleardoubleoddpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{This is a Section}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\section{A Second Section}
\subsection{This is a Sub-section}
\blindtext
\section{A Second Section}
\subsection{This is a Sub-section}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to use a smaller skip before section titles on a new page than the normal `beforeskip`, you can use something like

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\sectionlinesformat
  {\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}}
  {\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\vspace*{7pt}\raggedsection\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother
```

But then you have to decrease the `beforeskip` by the same length. In the example `beforeskip` would be 12pt-7pt=5pt.

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-5pt,afterskip=10pt]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[beforeskip=-5pt,afterskip=8pt]{subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,english,openright, bibliography=totoc,
  parskip=half-
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,margin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.75cm,headheight=18pt,headsep=8pt,footskip=26pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage[automark, headsepline, footsepline, plainfootsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark[chapter]{chapter} 
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}
\ifoot*{Test}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=12pt,afterskip=12pt]{chapter}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\sffamily\LARGE}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-5pt,afterskip=10pt]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[beforeskip=-5pt,afterskip=8pt]{subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\sffamily\normalsize}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\sectionlinesformat
  {\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}}
  {\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\vspace*{7pt}\raggedsection\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\textwidth}% default width for \includegraphics
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter{Introduction}
\Blindtext
\cleardoubleoddpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{This is a Section}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\section{A Second Section}
\subsection{This is a Sub-section}
\blindtext
\section{A Second Section}
\subsection{This is a Sub-section}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you maybe explain how the command you use works, so that I could adapt it that it fits my format ? I googled a bit but I dont really get it oO. Thanks in advance

Comment: @KiW I haved added another version. But it would be much better if you simple enlarge `headsep` for all pages instead of patching `\sectionlinesformat`. A different skip above sections on top of a page and above normal text is unusual.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Well unusual is not neccessarily bad is it ? But I will consider your advice!